# Java can't reach case 283 in switch

Tags: java, int, switch-statement

I had a weird problem with java, while working with Sockets I created a `case  LOGOUT:` (283) for the server to handle (client sends different ints to specify a service request to server), but in my switch the LOGOUT case was unreachable for some reason (IntelliJ told me that this statement was unreachable). So I tried `System.out.println(ServiceId)` and it was always a different number (not a random one) from 283, it was really weird. I solved this problem by changing the number. Obviously the number 283 wasn't in no other variable. 
Could it be Java that use a final static int with value 283 for something else?

P.S  : Could it be that switch has maximum number of statement where this number is less than 283?

```
    private static void getService(Socket s) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = s.getInputStream();
        int servId = inputStream.read();
        OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
        Runnable task;
        System.out.println("***************** " + servId); // this servID should be the number 283 but it's not.
        switch(servId) {
            case REPLY_EMAIL:
            case FORWARD_EMAIL:
            case REPLY_ALL_EMAIL:
            case WRITE_EMAIL:
                outputStream.write(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
                task = new EmailReceiver(s,lock, servId, serverLog);
                threadPool.execute(task);
                break;

            case LOGOUT:
                outputStream.write(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
                threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String user = Utils.getUser(s);
                            serverLog.writeLog("L'utente " + user + " si è disconnesso.");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;

            case READ_ALL_EMAILS:
                outputStream.write(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
                task = new EmailReader(s, serverLog);
                threadPool.execute(task);
                break;

            case USER_LIST:
                outputStream.write(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
                task = new UserGetter(s, serverLog);
                threadPool.execute(task);
                break;

            case LOGIN:
                outputStream.write(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
                task = new UserLogin(s, serverLog);
                threadPool.execute(task);
                break;

            case DELETE_EMAIL:
                outputStream.write(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
                task = new EmailDelete(s, serverLog);
                threadPool.execute(task);
                break;

            case NOTIFICATION:
                outputStream.write(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
                task = new Notificator(s, serverLog);
                threadPool.execute(task);
                break;

            default:
                serverLog.writeLog("Errore di Richiesta");
                outputStream.write(FAILURE_RESPONSE);
                break;
        }
    }
```

```
package common;

public class ServiceID {

    public static final int WRITE_EMAIL = 84;
    public static final int READ_ALL_EMAILS = 50;
    public static final int FORWARD_EMAIL = 94;
    public static final int REPLY_EMAIL = 95;
    public static final int REPLY_ALL_EMAIL = 96;
    public static final int DELETE_EMAIL = 100;
    public static final int LOGIN = 11;
    public static final int USER_LIST = 111;
    public static final int SUCCESS_RESPONSE = 1;
    public static final int FAILURE_RESPONSE = -1;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION = 118;
    public static final int EMAIL_NOT_FOUND = 404;
    public static final int LOGOUT = 283;
}
```

these 2 pieces of code are the functions where I get the ServiceID from InputStream.
The other class is all the possible serviceID number.
Don't write : " you are probably pass serviceID wrongly", because this is not the case, all other ServiceID working properly.

Comment: That probably means you already have a `case 283`

Comment: Is `A` or any other value used in a case label in the switch statement also equal to `283`?

Comment: another things, is not a switch problem, because the serviceID changed when read from inputstream by the Server

Comment: no rgettman, as i wrote other statement aren't equal to 283, that's the weird thing...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Don't describe your code, post it as [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) to let us reproduce your problem. Without it we are just playing guessing game, instead of debugging.

Comment: What is `ServiceID`? Looks like a class name, not a variable name, and it's definitely not the `servId` declared 3 lines above. --- What's the relevance to this question of the code preceding the `switch` statement?

Comment: ok i modified the question by adding the function where the problem is showing, and a class used to declare all the possible service ID.

Comment: That still isn't [mcve] because we can't compile it from other reasons than stated in question. Also you claim that problem is with value 283 but your example sets `public static final int LOGOUT = 12;`.

Comment: yes i edited the logout now, i wrote the working code. about the not minimal, i don't really now how can i insert 3-4 other classes, is too big.

Comment: Lets be clear are you talking about an "unreachable code" compilation error?  Or a compilation warning?  Or are you saying that the `case LOGOUT:` case is never taken at runtime?

Comment: Adding the other 3-4 classes wouldn't be _minimal_, would it? The point of a [mcve] is to have just enough code to fully reproduce the problem—don't include any irrelevant stuff. In order to produce an MCVE you may have to create it from scratch.

Comment: @StephenC I believe the OP is getting a warning from an IntelliJ code inspection that's aware of the contract of `InputStream#read`.

Comment: Yes ... well ... I had inferred that it was something like that.  I was trying to encourage the OP to be clear and explicit when describing the symptoms in his Question.  What he wrote is open to misinterpretation, and I suspect that most of us *did* misinterpret it.

Comment: @StephenC I actually was also trying to nudge the OP indirectly while also pinging you just in case you hadn't considered that possibility. There's a chance the OP doesn't know what a code inspection is and has simply assumed the problem is being reported by the compiler.

Comment: no it's not, it was a warning, but it wasn't clear. another-dave gave a good question but what about 404 that is working properly, indeed the value of inputstream.read() is 50 ( no sense)

Comment: Huh?  50 is READ_ALL_EMAILs.   I think that part of problem here is that someone has just thrown a bunch of constants into the class without naming to make it clear that they have different purposes.  I can see codes that represent *commands* or *actions* and others that probably represent *responses*.  Its a bit of a mess really.

Comment: EMAIL_NOT_FOUND is not used in the switch, so it is immaterial that its value exceeds 255.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If InputStream is `java.io.InputStream`, the return value is an 8-bit value (or -1), so it will not match 283.

> public abstract int read()
>                     throws IOException
>
> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0
>   to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been
>   reached, the value -1 is returned.

Comment: Just to add some clarification: I highly doubt the OP is getting a _compilation_ warning or error. It's probably one of IntelliJ's [_code inspections_](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) that has analyzed the code and, knowing that `read` will never return a value greater than 255, has warned the OP the case will never occur. But the compiler only knows `read` returns an `int` and has no idea about the valid range of results. In other words, this is the IDE issuing a warning, not the compiler.

Comment: oh wait, but what about    -->  public static final int EMAIL_NOT_FOUND = 404; it's bigger

Comment: yes Slaw is the a IDE warning, not a compiler error.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that IntelliJ detected all this, but it will certainly prevent correct execution of the code.

Comment: @user207421 I tried a similar setup to the OP's code and the warning I get is from an inspection; specifically, from the `Java → Probable bugs → Constant conditions & exceptions` inspection.

Comment: The `EMAIL_NOT_FOUND` constant wouldn't work  in the switch case either.  But I note that it isn't used in the switch.  My guess is that it has another purpose ... or is not used at all.  Look through the codebase for places where it is actually used.  Maybe you can infer its meaning from that.

Comment: Re: IDE vs. compiler - yeah, I assumed that it was some fancy IDE diagnostic rather than the actual Java compiler, but since I don't have that IDE, I couldn't check. The important point to me was that *something* was diagnosing it.

Comment: yes, EMAIL_NOT_FOUND is for another case, and it's not in the switch, thank you for your answer. I solved the problem by changing the number ( as i said before), but i was too curious of this problem and so i decided to open a question in stackoverflow, just for curiosity.